# In Adacore's GPR file, how can I set the compiler to exclude file with full path

Tags: compilation, ada, gprbuild

I have a project which contains several files which have the same name but in differents folders.

Ex :

```
 ->sources
    ->src 
      - a.c
      - b.c
    ->stub
      - a.c
      - z.c
```

In my gprfile I included the source with

```
for Source_Dirs use ( "sources/**" )
```

Now, I want to ignore the files in src by using the primitive "Excluded_Source_File".

Unfortunatly, this primitive needs a file name, and not a full path, so when I want to ignore a.c, it ignore the both files in src and stub.

```
for Excluded_Source_Files use ( "sources/src/a.c" ); -- KO by gprbuild
for Excluded_Source_Files use ( "a.c" ); -- OK but ignore both
```

Does anyone know how can I do this, without alterate the current folder architecture and without rename files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a project extension, ie. create a second project file, which extends the first. In this seconds project file, you can override `a.c`

```
project Stubbed extends "my_project.gpr" is
   for Source_Dirs use ("stub");
end Stubbed;
```

You can read more about project extentions in the [GPRBuild User Guide](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#project-extension)

Answer (score 7):

I would use [scenario variables](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gprbuild/html/gprbuild_ug/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#scenarios-in-projects); also, it sounds as though `Excluded_Source_Dirs` would be useful.

```
type Source_T is ("normal", "stubbed");
Sources : Source_T := external ("SOURCES", "normal");
```

then either

```
for Source_Dirs use ("sources/**");
case Sources is
   when "normal" =>
      for Excluded_Source_Dirs use ("sources/stub");
   when "stubbed" =>
      for Excluded_Source_Dirs use ("sources/src");
end case;
```

or

```
for Source_Dirs use ("sources");
case Sources is
   when "normal" =>
      for Source_Dirs use project'Source_Dirs & "sources/src";
   when "stubbed" =>
      for Source_Dirs use project'Source_Dirs & "sources/stub";
end case;
```

In either case,

```
gprbuild -P prj
```

(you could add the defaulted `-XSOURCES=normal`) or

```
gprbuild -P prj -XSOURCES=stubbed
```